# Changing colors in a shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, minecraft

I have a Grey Scale Shader for the Shaders Mod for Minecraft. I have the final.fsh, and it works real nice with this resource pack:

[image]
"Craftboy Grey"

However, I'd like to modify the shader to show up in green, similar to the grey does.

[image]
"Craftboy Green"

The reason I need the shader, is to modify all the colors the resource pack cannot, and also change other player's skins to the same scale, without them needing to manually do it.

Here's the code for the shader:

```
// Grayscale shader by daxnitro.
// Small edit by Edrem
// It makes the green brighter =D

uniform sampler2D sampler0;
uniform sampler2D sampler1;
uniform sampler2D sampler2;

uniform float near;
uniform float far;

float getBrightness(vec4 color);
float getDepth(vec2 coord);

void applyEffect() {
        float brightness = getBrightness(gl_FragColor);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(brightness, brightness, brightness, gl_FragColor[3]);
}

void main() {
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D(sampler0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);

        gl_FragColor = baseColor;

        float depth = getDepth(gl_TexCoord[0].st);

        if (gl_FragColor[3] == 0.0) {
                gl_FragColor = gl_Fog.color;
        }

        applyEffect(); 
}

float getBrightness(vec4 color) {
        return color[0] * 0.299f + color[1] * 0.587f + color[2] * 0.114f;
}

float getDepth(vec2 coord) {
        float depth = texture2D(sampler1, coord).x;
        float depth2 = texture2D(sampler2, coord).x;
        if (depth2 < 1.0) {
                depth = depth2;
        }

    depth = 2.0 * near * far / (far + near - (2.0 * depth - 1.0) * (far - near));

    return depth;
}
```

Comment: Try playing around with that last assignment to `gl_FragColor` inside `applyEffect`.

Comment: @StefanHanke Danke, Herr Steven. Unfortunately, though, editing that makes the mod fail to initialize the pack. 

To others: If this cannot be done, it would be nice to know, but if it can be, knowing how would be nice~

Comment: Additionally, should I move this to another forum? I know not if this is the correct place for this to sit. After a short bit of clicking, I noticed there is also a game development forum for this as well. Would this belong there? It may not be a game in itself, but it's for one.

Comment: IMO the question is correctly located. Does the "pack" spit out any additional relevant information after your changes? What did you try?

Comment: @StefanHanke The pack itself does not do any shading, it simply replaces the textures with "Gameboy" like retro grey ones. I use a greyscale shader to change player skins, and the sunset to grey to match the textures. What I wish to use is the green pack, and modify the greyscale shader to change the colours to various forms of green, to be used with the green pack.

Answer (score 2):

To make it "green scale" instead of grey scale, write the brightness only to the green component of the output:

```
void applyEffect() {
    float brightness = getBrightness(gl_FragColor);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, brightness, 0.0, gl_FragColor[3]);
}
```

If you want more overall brightness while still having the whole thing tinted green, you can add some brightness back in the red and blue components. For example:

```
    gl_FragColor = vec4(brightness * vec3(0.5, 1.0, 0.5), gl_FragColor[3]);
```

Comment: A more general way might be to multiply the brightness by the color you want. "Greenish" may mean there's actually a little red or blue in it, for example. So maybe 'vec4 desiredColor = (0.1, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0); gl_FragColor = glFragColor * desiredColor;`?

Comment: @user1118321 Unfortunately, inserting that bit into the final.fsh caused it to fail to initialize.

Comment: @AlexanderKeith: I thought you wanted it green? What I posted will use the brightness for just the green component, instead of applying it to all the RGB components. If you want what the other comment above suggests, the first part should be something like `const vec4 desiredColor = vec4(0.1, 1.0, 0.2, 1.0);`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Your code makes it green, yes, but it's very dark green. I was looking for a more mint green. (I replied with this a bit ago, but I had used a + instead of an @, so it did not notify you. My apologies.)

Comment: @AlexanderKeith: I saw it, and updated the answer in response. See the last part about adding more brightness.